# StrokeEnd not drawing full circle

Tags: ios, swift, animation, progress

I'm trying to build a progress view for a Music Player. I am totaly new to programming in general and now really reached a dead end here.

My progress works fine. I am animatig "strokeEnd" with the value (value/duration) of the Mediafile, but strokeEnd only ever reaches have of the circle. However, the song is then finished as well, this is why I think, somewhere it calculats wrong.

It is a very simple Shaplayer I am using.

```
var value: CGFloat  = 0.0{
didSet {
  redrawStrokeEnd() }
}

private func setupShapeLayer(shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer) {
let startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_2 * 2 + M_PI_2)
progressLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:centerPoint, radius:   CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 + 5, startAngle:startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true).CGPath
progressLayer.strokeStart = 0.0
progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0 }

func redrawStrokeEnd() {
progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(value / CGFloat(duration))}
```

value = currentTime and duration = Playbackduration.
I can't figure out, why stroke End does not move the full circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're using the wrong constant?  As some of the other commenters have pointed out, a circle in radians traverses 2 * pi.  However the constant M_PI_2 is equal to (pi / 2)  So right now you're only traversing from (pi/2) -> (3pi/2)... or pi.  If you really want to start at pi/2 try:

```
let startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_2 + 2.0 * M_PI)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not strokeEnd the reason you see half circle. You just have wrong start and end angles for your path. You can set them as below to have a full circle :

```
let startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
let endAngle = CGFloat(5*M_PI_2)
```

Or better if you don't want to set angles by radians set them in degrees like this :

```
let startAngle = CGFloat(0 * M_PI / 180)
let endAngle = CGFloat(360 * M_PI / 180.0)
```

Comment: start angle in radians is 0 and the end angle is 2 * pi

Comment: Thanks so much, been fighting with that for days. Still have a lot to learn. All the solutions work fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the start angle and end angle in your code will work for you.

```
let startAngle = -90.0
let endAngle = -90.01
```